# Steiner-like systems with large edges and many intersections

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraph, combinatorial-designs

Let $l\geq 3$ be an integer. Is there $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a hypergraph $H=(\{1,\ldots,n\},E)$ with the following properties?

1. for all $e\in E$ we have $|e| \geq l$
2. $e_1\neq e_2 \in E \implies |e_1 \cap e_2|\leq 1 $
3. every edge intersects at least $n$ other edges, that is, for every $e\in E$ we have $|\{d\in E: d\neq e \text{ and } d\cap e\neq \emptyset\}|\geq n.$

(It would also be nice to know what the smallest value for $n$ is, given any $l \geq 3$. Obviously $n\geq 2l -1$ but this is a very weak lower bound.)

Comment: If by $n$ other edges you allow the edge itself, then yes.  Just take the Fano Plane.

Comment: Thanks for your example. No, I don't want to allow the edge itself.

Comment: Edited the post accordingly.

Comment: A finite projective plane is still a solution for any $n$. Or does $n$ denote $|V|$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $n =|V|$, forgot to put this in the post, will do so now.

Comment: Steiner triple systems.

Comment: Oh - interesting, thanks Brendan. I will edit the question, generalising to the Steiner systems you mention